# Android: TextView Not showing all letters

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

A simple [AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) is giving me unexpected results: missing letters. This only happens in an AlertDialog. In my theme I have set `monospace` as my default font and then I replaced the `monospace` font with a custom typeface (.otf) that was provided to me by the client.

I get expected results on Android 25 and can reproduce the issue on 19. I haven't cared to try any version between those.

Some things I have tried:

- Removing the custom font to see if it was the culprit, resulting in losing all text rather than bits. Also tried switching the custom font to `sans` or another typeface as my default.
- Creating custom dialog theme
- Changing colors to see if the text was somehow matching the background, and I don't believe that is the case.
- Hardcoding text. No difference
- Using `android.app.AlertDialog`rather than `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`. No Difference.
- I have styles for DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog. I tried removing those to see if they were interfering. Obviously not, where those styles are vs 21> and my problem is in 19. I have not specified any styles or themes for AlertDialog. My root theme is `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar`. The rest of the theme only sets primary and secondary colors. Nothing too extravagant.

**Android 25** *expected results*

[image]

**Android 19** *wtf results*

[image]

This is the extent of the code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

public static Maybe<Boolean> showConfirmDialog(Context context, int title, int message, int positive, int negative) {
        return Maybe.create(e -> {
            final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton(positive, (d, w) -> e.onSuccess(true))
                    .setNegativeButton(negative, (d, w) -> e.onSuccess(false))
                    .show();

             dialog.setOnDismissListener(d -> e.onComplete());

             e.setCancellable(() -> {
                if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
                   dialog.dismiss();
             });

        });
}
```

I ended up creating a dialog from scratch because I couldn't figure out what was going on in the amount of time I had, but it bothered me enough that I need to get a solution.

Comment: I haven't been able to recreate your symptoms.  Can you share more information?  What is the font you are using, your styles.xml file, the code you used to set the typeface, etc.

Comment: This problem originally occurred yesterday. I am trying to recreate it myself and now I can't. I am not sure what is more frustrating: the problem itself, or the fact I can't recreate the problem.

Comment: I notice it will happen on other views. But not only missing letters, but missing _parts_ of a letter. If i scroll out of view and back it will fix itself. Maybe this is an emulator problem?

Comment: Weird.  Could be an emulator problem, or a problem with that emulator on the specific hardware you're running.  Can you change the emulator settings or perhaps try a different monitor?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with supprot alertdialog. I resolved it by custom theme dialog. Try this variant. Add to your builder custom theme:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.DefaultAlertDialogTheme)
```

And here your style.xml:

```
<style name="DefaultAlertDialogTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
</style>
```